# Program throwing timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, sockets, timeout

I dono what is the reason but my ruby program throws timeout error suddently

```
/home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': execution expired (Net::OpenTimeout)
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:161:in `request'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/consumer_token.rb:25:in `request'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:12:in `request'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/access_token.rb:27:in `get'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/semantics3-0.04/lib/semantics3.rb:36:in `_make_request'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/semantics3-0.04/lib/semantics3.rb:217:in `run_query'
from /home/mounarajan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/semantics3-0.04/lib/semantics3.rb:80:in `get_products'
from project.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from project.rb:31:in `each'
from project.rb:31:in `each_with_index'
from project.rb:31:in `block in <main>'
from project.rb:30:in `open'
from project.rb:30:in `<main>'
```

Please help me to overcome this problem

Comment: Post the code from `project.rb` where it's an issue.

Comment: @japed is it a code error or due to api or internet probelm?

Comment: Possibly, but until you post some code no-one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the web service that you are accessing ever worked?

Then it is probably not available and you can only wait until is up again.

If you are developing the access for first time, may be a firewall is blocking you, or the service url has not been properly written

Comment: my program is running through file which has 5000 rows.the program works upto 1700 rows after then it throws error like this

Comment: I have no idea about your implementation details. What is sure is that in that moment you are accessing an external service that is down... Look at your `lib/semantics3.rb:217`. If you perform different requests per line, then you have to guess which service is down. For that, the best is to log the service name before calling it